# How does vim save files?

Tags: vim, filesystems

I believe it's designed to be atomic, and I've heard that vim will save to a temporary directory and then `mv` the temp file over the old file to ensure that EITHER the old version OR the new version is present, and never half of one or no file at all, even if the power is turned off mid-save.

Does anyone have more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about the general approach; for more information, see `:help backup`.

You can fine-tune the approach via settings; this is important when you deal with hard-lined files or use APIs like *inotify* to react to file system changes.

Additionally, the swapfile (`:help swap-file`) and persistent undo (`:help persistent-undo`) help you with avoiding any data loss, even in case of a disk crash.

Answer (score 7):

How this is done depends on the values of several options.

The main option that affects this is `backupcopy`, on unix systems this defaults to `yes` on other systems it defaults to `auto`. Only if it is set to `no` can you be assured that writes will be done like in your question. When set to `yes` vim will instead overwrite the original file contents after making a backup copy. If set to `auto`, it will behave as in the question if it detects that attributes can be passed on and the file isn't a link (either a symlink or a hard link). There are additional values for the option to have it break links, see the help for that option.

Other options that affect this are `backup`, `writebackup`. At least one of those must be set for a backup to be made at all. If no backup is done, the original file contents will be overwritten. The `writebackup` option defaults to on as long as vim was compiled with support for it. There's also the `backupskip` option which specifies a list of file patterns for which no backups will be done; if one of those patterns match the file, again no backup will be done and the original file contents will be overwritten.